# Cypher query to match multiple Destination nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement where i want to include multiple destination nodes in my path.

[image: Sample Graph]

My requirement:

I want to find all the suppliers and the RISK associated with the Suppliers for a particular product.

Query to return all suppliers for a Product.

```
match path =(p:Product{name:"Product2"}) <-[*..10] -(:Supplier)
return path
```

This query returns me all the suppliers for a particular product

[image]

Query to return suppliers affected by RISK for a product

```
match path =(p:Product{name:"Product2"}) <-[*..10] -(:Supplier)-[:AFFECTEDBY]-(:RISK)
return path
```

[image]

As you can see the 2 suppliers (name:"SupplierN+1") were not retrieved in the above graph

Can you please help me with the query to retrieve BOTH Suppliers (3 suppliers) and RISK associated with for a particular product.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH p:Product{name:"Product2"}) <-[*..10] -(s:Supplier)
OPTIONAL MATCH s-[:AFFECTED_BY]-(r:RISK)
RETURN s, r, p
```

OPTIONAL MATCH is like OUTER JOIN of SQL. It will optionally match :RISK nodes for the :SUPPLIER. It will return all :SUPPLIER nodes which have or don't have relation to :RISK nodes.